# Is there any way to install mod_csrfprotector on Windows Wamp?

Tags: apache, csrf, apache-modules

I tried to download mod_csrfprotector.so placed to the modules folder and also add the following configuration in httpd.conf. However, the server will not start anymore.

```
LoadModule csrf_protector_module modules/mod_csrfprotector.so

<IfModule csrf_protector_module>
  csrfpEnable on
  csrfpAction forbidden
  errorCustomMessage "Access forbidden"
  jsFilePath "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mebjas/mod_csrfprotector/master/js/csrfprotector.js" 
  tokenLength 20
  disablesJsMessage "please enable javascript "
  verifyGetFor *://*/*
</IfModule>
```